# Incompatibility between siunitx and gb4e

Tags: packages, siunitx, incompatibility, linguistics, gb4e

It looks like the siunitx package and the gb4e package are in conflict.

More specifically, the following code would not run:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\def\fg{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
yo

\SI{30}{\degreeCelsius}
\end{document}
```

Returning the error

> Command \rmfamily invalid in math mode

Now, I know that the packages *linguex* and *siunitx* are in conflict, and I know how to resolve that: load *linguex* first, (re)define \fg (the command in conflict) to null, and then load *siunitx*, i.e.

```
\usepackage{linguex}
\def\fg{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

But this *does not resolve the problem here*.

The code at the top would work however if we do not use the command `\SI{}{}` at all. i.e. if we remove the line

```
\SI{30}{\degreeCelsius}
```

then the code at the top would work.

**(Note**: Even if we were to use just

```
\SI{30}{degreeCelsius}
```

the code would still not work.**)**

- What other commands might be in conflict?
- Or is there any other reason the two are in conflict?

Comment: @LianTzeLim This is a big overgeneralization. If you add `\noautomath` immediately after loading the package it should pose few problems.

Comment: Sorry @AlanMunn, I take that back—gb4e did give me quite a bit of headache with most other packages I used.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The cause of the problem

The redefinition of `^` and `_` that `gb4e` does has nothing to do with this problem, because (as @cfr notes) it isn't solved by `\noautomath`. The problem is some code in the package that checks for the presence of a very old LaTeX kernel.

Changes to the current LaTeX kernel that happened a few years ago have caused this code to do the opposite of what was intended. I thought this bug had been fixed, but apparently it hasn't. I'll re-notify Alexis Dimitriadis, the maintainer of `gb4e`.

### Workaround

*Before* you load the `gb4e` package, add the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\new@fontshape{}
\makeatother
```

It's also a good idea to load `gb4e` after `siunitx`.  If you don't you will need to add `\noautomath` immediately after loading `gb4e`.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\makeatletter
\def\new@fontshape{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}


\SI{30}{\degreeCelsius}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and solution! This is fascinating.

Comment: Thank you very much for this fix. It solved the same error I was getting (`! LaTeX Error: Command \rmfamily invalid in math mode.`) as well as a couple of weird formatting of `\mathit{}` symbols.

Comment: "I'll re-notify Alexis Dimitriadis, the maintainer of gb4e." Did he answer? I'm still getting this in 2022

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I’ll try again. :)

Answer (score 2):

Package `gb4e` redefines `^`, so you need to use `\textsuperscript` instead of `^` for degrees.  The way to make `siunitx` to do this is to select text mode for the units.  Also, in this case you do not need to redefine `\fg` unless you want to do it for other purposes.

This works:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[mode=text]{siunitx}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
yo

\SI{30}{\degreeCelsius}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And `\noautomath` doesn't help ....