# Times font usage changes the alignment (gb4e.sty)

Tags: gb4e, timesfont

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree, tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{gb4e}%


\begin{document}
\newcommand{\LT}[1]{{\Large #1}}
\newcommand{\TS}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\TSS}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\erg}{\textsc{erg}}
\newcommand{\BF}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\wh}{\textsc{wh}}
\newcommand{\SC}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\BFSC}[1]{\textbf{\textsc{#1}}}

\begin{exe}
\ex \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}%\toprule[-18pt]
\label{candytree}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node(a){\LT{[}\TS{CP}~Op\TS{i}~~~...~~\LT{[}\TS{TP}~~{\it t}\TS{i}(\erg)\BF{[\wh]}~~...~~\LT{[}\TS{ApplP}~[\TS{DP(IO)}~~{\it pro}\TS{i}\BF{[\wh]}~~~]~...~\LT{]~]~]}};
\draw[semithick] (-2.8,-.2) -- (-2.8,-.5);
\draw[semithick] (-2.8,-.5) -- (-4.9,-.5);
\draw[semithick,->] (-4.9,-.5) -- (-4.9,-.2);
\draw[thick,->] (-2.8,-.2)..controls +(south:.6) and +(south:.6)..(2.6,-.2);
\node(b) at (4.3,-.5) {\SC{Agree via binding}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

It creates the `output` as:

[image]

When I use the font package `times`, then the alignment changed as:

[image]

The alignment as in `CMR` font is required, please advise what went wrong...

Comment: `\usepackage{mathptmx}` (or even better `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead of `\usepackage{times}` (note that this package has been obsolete for more than 20 years).

Comment: @egreg per your advise, I've changed the preamble to `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree, tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{gb4e}`, but still the same problem exists...Please advise...

Comment: Where are you using the `(a)` coordinate? The arrow is placed at some point that will depend on the width of the characters. Changing the font, will inevitably misplace the arrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provided code defines the arrow positions with absolute coordinates such as `(-2.8,-.5) -- (-4.9,-.5)`. When the width of the example changes because of a different font then also these coordinates should be changed.

To make the code more flexible you can use the `tikzmark` tikzlibrary, that allows you to add markers to any position in your code. You can refer to these markers within a `tikzpicture`. This also allows you to use the normal `gb4e` syntax to create examples, instead of using `tikz` for the sentence.

As an example, in the code below a mark `cp` is defined for the bracket [<sub>CP</sub> with the code `\lb{CP}\tikzmark{cp}`, and another one for the bracket [<sub>TP</sub>. After finishing the `gb4e` sentence, a `tikzpicture` is added using the keys `remember picture, overlay`. Within this tikzpicture the coordinates defined earlier are used to draw an arrow, with the basic syntax `\draw[->] (pic cs:tp) -- (pic cs:cp)`. The `pic cs:` part is needed to specify that this is a tikzmark coordinate.

To finetune the positioning you can use the `shift` option when referring to the coordinates, for example `([shift={(-8pt,-5pt)}]pic cs:tp)` to shift the anchor down and left.

The corners in the arrows are made by inserting a relative point `+(x,y)` in the drawing path, which means that the arrow is first drawn to this point and then to the second coordinate. This creates the first corner. The second corner is achieved by using `-|` for the second segment.

The curved arrow is made with the syntax `\draw (a) to (b)` where the `to` keyword allows for the options `in` and `out` that specify the angle of the curve.

For the Times font `newtxtext,newtxmath` is used as a modern alternative to the `times` package.

Full MWE below. Note that you might need to compile two times to allow for `tikzmark` to write the correct coordinates to the `aux` file.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\makeatletter
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364179/
\def\new@fontshape{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex \lb{CP}\tikzmark{cp} Op_i \ldots \lb{TP}\tikzmark{tp} \textit{t}_i(\textsc{erg\textbf{[wh]}} \ldots \lb{ApplP}\lb{DP(IO)} \textit{pro}_i\tikzmark{pro}\textsc{\textbf{[wh]}} ] \ldots ] ] ]
\end{exe}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[semithick,->] ([shift={(-8pt,-5pt)}]pic cs:tp) -- +(0,-0.3) -| ([shift={(-8pt,-5pt)}]pic cs:cp);
\draw[semithick,->] ([shift={(-8pt,-5pt)}]pic cs:tp) to [out=340,in=200] ([shift={(-8pt,-5pt)}]pic cs:pro) node[below,xshift=10mm] {\textsc{Agree via binding}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It's working perfect...Thanks a lot... Apart from this, can you help me on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599218/is-this-possible-to-change-the-arrow-heads-like-as-tikz-qtree-currently-using please...